# Display JSON Response in List View C# MVC

Tags: c#, json, layout, ienumerable

I am new to C#, Android was my past. So sorry if I am not explaining properly or understanding.
Trying to figure out how to display more than one of my JSON responses in a view.  Here is my class to go with shtml:

```
 public class ArtistInformation : IEnumerable
{
    [Display(Name = "Song Title:")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Album Title:")]
    public string Album { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    public string Image { get; set; }
}
```

shtml:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">

        <h2>Forecast for the selected city</h2>

        <label asp-for="Name"></label>
        <span class="badge">@Model.Name</span>
        <br />

        <label asp-for="Album"></label>
        <span class="badge">@Model.Album</span>
        <br />

        <label asp-for="Image"></label>
        <div class="display-field">
            <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Image)/>"

        <br />
    </div>
```

Here is my controller where I have hard coded first position to display to make sure it worked:

```
 public IActionResult ArtistInformation(string artistName)
    {
        ArtistInfoResponse artistResponse = _musicRepository.GetArtistResponse(artistName);
        ArtistInformation viewModel = new ArtistInformation();
        
        if (artistResponse != null)
        {
            viewModel.Name = artistResponse.Data[1].Title;
            viewModel.Album = artistResponse.Data[1].Album.Title;
            viewModel.Image = artistResponse.Data[1].Album.Cover;

        }
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Now I want to repeat this view with my entire response.  I've read up on IEnumerable but can't wrap my head how to apply if this is what I need.

Here is where I use RestSharp to get my JSON response:

```
ArtistInfoResponse IMusicRepository.GetArtistResponse(string artistName)
    {
        artistName = (char)34 + artistName + (char)34;  //ensure the string is wa
        RestClient client = new RestClient($"https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:{artistName}");
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            // Deserialize the string content into JToken object
           // var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content);
            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<ArtistInfoResponse>>(response.Content);
            // Deserialize the JToken object into our ArtistInfoResponse Class
            return content.ToObject<ArtistInfoResponse>();  // this line doesn't work now
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT ADDING CLASS****************************

```
 public class ArtistInfoResponse : IEnumerable
{
    public SongInfo[] Data { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public string Next { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class SongInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Readable { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Title_short { get; set; }
    public string Title_version { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
    public bool Explicit_lyrics { get; set; }
    public int Explicit_content_lyrics { get; set; }
    public int Explicit_content_cover { get; set; }
    public string Preview { get; set; }
    public string Md5_image { get; set; }
    public Artist Artist { get; set; }
    public Album Album { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string Picture_small { get; set; }
    public string Picture_medium { get; set; }
    public string Picture_big { get; set; }
    public string Picture_xl { get; set; }
    public string Tracklist { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Cover { get; set; }
    public string Cover_small { get; set; }
    public string Cover_medium { get; set; }
    public string Cover_big { get; set; }
    public string Cover_xl { get; set; }
    public string Md5_image { get; set; }
    public string Tracklist { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share your **ArtistInfoResponse** class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through your data because it is a list.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item.Name</div>
    <div>@item.Album</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting rid of the class views to populate an shtml for I suppose I don't fully understand this infrastructure.  I also removed the IEnumerable for the serialized object itself is IEnumerable (I think).  I now have the shtml like this:

```
@model MyMusicApp.Models.ArtistInfoResponse
```

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Artist Information";
}

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">

        <h2>Song Titles and Albums for @Model.Data[1].Artist.Name</h2>

        @foreach (var item in Model.Data)
        {
            <span class="badge">@item.Title</span>
            <br />

            <span class="badge">@item.Album.Title</span>
            <br />

            <img src="@Url.Content(item.Album.Cover)" />
            <hr />
        }

    </div>

</div>

<div class="container">

    <div class="form-group col-md-offset-3 col-md-5">

        <form method="get">
            <button asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SearchArtist" class="btn btn-success">Return</button>
        </form>
```

And get it populated passing it from the controller to the view:

```
 public IActionResult ArtistInformation(string artistName)
    {
        ArtistInfoResponse artistResponse = _musicRepository.GetArtistResponse(artistName);
       
        return View(artistResponse);
    }
```

My client I have in a separate class where this contains the GetArtistResponse:

```
ArtistInfoResponse IMusicRepository.GetArtistResponse(string artistName)
    {
        artistName = (char)34 + artistName + (char)34;
        var client = new RestClient($"https://api.deezer.com/search?q=artist:{artistName}");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            // Deserialize the string content into JToken object
            var content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(response.Content);

            // Deserialize the JToken object into our ArtistInfoResponse Class
            return content.ToObject<ArtistInfoResponse>();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

}